# Warning Error encountered during contract execution

Tags: erc-20

I got this error while transacting to erc-20 compatible wallet address. The details can be found on this link: 
https://etherscan.io/tx/0x504602fd654b768ae3e44c71841d002c85e079e9c7d3520a6316126f6578463c
The problem is that whether such a transaction means I lost my ETH? Does anyone have lost their transaction if it is failed like this? If it is not lost how many chances are there I recover back my ETH amount? If it is possible, then how? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The transaction failed because it ran out of gas.

A failed transaction has no effect except for consuming gas. So the account that sent this transaction lost the gas cost of 0.000083762 (~$0.03), and otherwise nothing happened.

Comment: But the said ETH amount left my account. It has been upto 04 days and I did not get back my ETH to my account. Does it mean I am able to recover it back? If yes, what should be the procedure.

Comment: Was this via some sort of exchange?

Comment: If so, the ether was in _their_ account, and it still is. If they lost track of the fact that they owe it to you, that's a problem on their side, and you'll need to talk to them about it.